# if $f$ is in $C^{2}$ then why does $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)}{u^{2}}du$ necessarily exist

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, convergence-divergence, continuity

if $f$ is in $C^{2}$ then why does $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)}{u^{2}}du$ necessarily exist?

Clearly $u\to\frac{f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)}{u^{2}}$ converges to $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ as $u \to 0$, how does this help me prove the above?

Attempt:

Let $\delta, \; \varepsilon > 0$, then it follows that $\int_{\delta}^{1}\frac{f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)}{u^{2}}du$ exists, as we can bound the integrand by $4\frac{\lvert f\rvert}{\delta ^{2}}$

Now consider that for all $u$ smaller than some $\delta > 0$  we have $\lvert f^{\prime\prime}(x)-\frac{f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)}{u^{2}}\rvert \leq \varepsilon$, then we obtain:

\begin{align}&\int_{0}^{\delta}\lvert \frac{f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)}{u^{2}}\lvert du \\ \leq &\int_{0}^{\delta}\lvert \frac{f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)}{u^{2}}-f^{\prime\prime}(x)\lvert du+\delta\lvert f^{\prime\prime}(x)\rvert\\ \leq &\varepsilon \delta+\delta\lvert f^{\prime\prime}(x)\rvert\end{align}

Comment: You want to use Taylor. Then you get $$ f(x-u)+f(x+u)-2 f(x)= (f(x)-f'(x)u + O(u^2))+(f(x)+f'(x)u + O(u^2))-2f(x) = O(u^2).$$ So we get that the integrand is bounded and hence the integral converges.

Comment: +1 for adding an attempt, let's see if it works out.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I believe that we actually do not even need continuity of the second derivative right?

Comment: @SABOY You are right , I don't think so : you are *fixing* $x$, so the integral doesn't depend upon how $f$ behaves with respect to changing $x$. Although, I'd imagine that if $f$ was $C^2$ then this expression will obviously exist, but as a function of $x$ will also be continuous. I think a simple DCT or something will do it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon great! Is my attempt correct?

Comment: @SABOY Was just about to write : I think it's fine!

Comment: +1 for attempt! You should note that the integrand has a problem only at $u=0$ but then its limit as $u\to 0$ exists so that problem is resolved. You don't need any more analysis beyond showing that limit of integrand as $u\to 0$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

for $u>0$, let  $g(u) = \frac{f(x+u)+f(x−u)−2f(x)}{u^2}$
be the integrand; for $u>0$ it is a $C^2$ function, while
(as you noted) it has a limit $\lim_{u\to 0} g(u)=f''(x)$; so you can set
$g(0)=f''(x)$; the function $g:[0,1]\to R$ so defined
is then continuous: by well known theorems, the integral is well defined.

Comment: +1 there. The existence of limit of integrand as $u\to 0$ is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Write
\begin{align}
f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)&=\int_0^1[f'(x+su)-f'(x-su)]\,u\,ds
\\
&=\int_0^1(1-s)\,[f''(x+su)+f''(x-su)]\,u^2\,ds=u^2g(x,u)
\end{align}
where $g$ a continuous function as $f''$ is continuous. Then the integral in question becomes
$$
\int_0^1\frac{f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)}{u^2}\,du=\int_0^1g(x,u)\,du
$$
which is an ordinary integral over a continuous function. One can probably find some interesting transformations by inserting $g$ back.
$$
=\int_0^1(1-s)\,[f'(x+s)-f'(x-s)] \,ds=...
$$